# Do we need to overload operator< in order to use set.find?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a class called `Person` and another class called `School`. In the second class I have a private field which is a set (of the standard library). The set represents the students (objects of the first class). In one of the functions of `School`, I want to check if a studet does not exist in the set of students. For that I do:

```
if (students.find(student) == students.end()) {
    // throw exception
}
```

I was wondering if I need to overload one of the comparison operators of `Person` because otherwise how `find` knows to compare the objects? Reading the docs I see that this method is only using `operator<`. Does it mean that I have to overload it in `Person`? If I don't overload it, does it use a default one? Does the compiler creates a default operator less? Otherwise, as I understand, it should fail building?

Comment: *Does the compiler creates a default operator less?* -- How could the compiler determine what makes a `Person` < another `Person`?  The age?  The height?  The weight?  Name length?  Only you know what the `<` criteria will be.

Comment: It could always compare addresses of the objects as default, like it does in other languages. So it means that I need to overload < operator, otherwise it will fail in building stage?

Comment: *It could always compare addresses of the objects as default, like it does in other languages.* -- Unless you store pointers, this does not happen.  Why not write a very [simple test?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f585ee98f9762464)

Comment: @paulsm4 `std::find()` uses `operator==`, but `std::set::find()` uses `operator<` by default instead, unless you provide a custom Comparator.

Answer (score 3):

1.: Actually overloading `operator<` is just 1 way the other way is to define a functor and give it to the set eg.:

```
class Comper_functor{
    bool operator()(const Person& a, const Person& b);
}
...
std::set<Person,Comper_functor> s;
```

works just fine if you want to avoid overloading `operator<`

2.: `operator<` (or the compere function) does not have to be a "logical" operator just a consistent one for `std::set`. So it is good if for any `Person a,b,c`

a) if `a<b` and `b<c` -> `a<c`

b) if `a<b` -> `!b>a`

c) if `!a<b` and `!b<a` -> `a==b`

The easiest way to make it work is compering the 2 person member by member.

Eg.: for a

```
class Ponit{
    double x,y;
    public:
    bool operator<(const point& o)const{
        if (x!=o.x) return x<o.x;
        return y<o.y;
    }
}
```

works fine. Even if a point is can't be "smaller" then an other one.

3.: in c++20 you can say in the class definition

```
std::weak_ordering operator<=>(const Person& o)const=default;
bool operator==(const Person& o)const=default;
```

To generate all operators `<,>,<=,>=,==,!=`

In older versions you have to define `operator<` manually

Answer (score 1):

Overloading the "less than" operator for a type is *an option*, but not necessarily the only way.

When you create a `std::set`, you can provide a *comparator* to compare objects.  By default, the comparator it uses is `std::less`, which will use `operator<`, but your comparator can do anything else, provided it meets the requirements of ordering properly.

Some examples:

```
#include <set>
#include <functional>

struct EvenOddIncreasing {
    bool operator()(int a, int b) const noexcept { 
        if ((a&1) < (b&1)) return true;
        if ((a&1) > (b&1)) return false;
        return a < b;
    }
};

std::set<int, EvenOddIncreasing> evenOddIncreasing{1,2,3,4,5};
std::set<int, std::greater<>> decreasing{1,2,3,4,5};
std::set<int, std::less<>> increasing{1,2,3,4,5};
```

The code above uses an `int`, which has `operator<` obviously defined for it, but since the `std::set` is passed explicit comparator types, it will use those for ordering.  Note, `evenOddIncreasing` is an example of a custom comparator that puts evens first, then odds, and in increasing order.

The above sets will have the following orderings:

```
even odd increasing...2 4 1 3 5
decreasing...5 4 3 2 1
increasing...1 2 3 4 5
```

In C++20, you could even use a lambda, but not with older versions of C++.

See it live:

https://godbolt.org/z/9ExhEGbb6